# What is the best easy way to move the directory C:\users to D:\users on windows server 2012 ,2016 or 2019?

Tags: windows

What is the best easy way to move the directory C:\users to D:\users on windows server 2012 ,2016 or 2019?

my disk C:\ is full...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to login with an administrador account, copy user profile to your D drive and modify registry keys to point where you copy all files.
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList

Before change registry keys make a backup exporting it.

If you need to free space on disk C you could use treesize to check if you can clean up unnused files.